# Prevent text from being cut off by background padding

Tags: html, css, background

I have a heading with padding:

[image: heading]

However at narrower screen widths the text gets cut off by the padding:

[image: heading cut off]

In this case, the bottom of the "y" gets cut off by the padding (and also letters like j, g, q, p). How can I fix this?

I tried `text-overflow: ellipsis` but that did not solve anything.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eap7xo8n/)

**Edit** Here is a better example of what I am looking for (created the example using my photo editor):

[image: goal]

Here the bottom of the "y" isn't cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase the line-height from the vertical :

```css
h1 span {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  line-height:calc(1em + 4px);
}
h1 + h1 span {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 6px 12px;
line-height:normal;}
h1 {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background:gray;
  overflow:hidden;;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>my heading fixed my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading</span>
</h1>
<h1>
  <span>my heading bugs my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading my heading</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix it without increasing the line height? It's a little to far apart especially when viewing from mobile. I am looking for something like the image in my post (keeping the line-height at 1).

Comment: @Cris, set bg-color inside h1 instead ? but not what you look for :(

Comment: @Cris , your vertical padding is the worrie, decrease it and what you remove from it, add it to the line height : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aLBYYZ (removed twice 4px top & bottom padding, added to line-height) side by side the buggy and the fix......